# Does openebs device localpv still work if I attach block device to another node?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, openebs

If I have 2 worker nodes in the k8s cluster like this.

- worker-1 <- bd1
- worker-2

I will use openebs device localpv as a storage solution.
Suppose I attach the device to the node worker 2 and delete the worker-1.

- worker-2 <- bd1

Is everything still working? If not, what solutions do you guys use for this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the case of openEBS, the node device manager will detect the device has been moved. Subsequent workload that claims the PV will be schedule on the worker-2 to consume the resource.